# Sugestions on Macro Usage

Tags: c++, macros, conways-game-of-life

Originally most lines of code were lengthy.  I decided to use macros to be short and clear.  I was wandering if using macros like this is bad practice.  I personally think it looks cleaner with the macros, but with the macros hiding names and functions some may be confused as to how I have implemented my methods.

**Original Code**

```
...
namespace ConwaysGameOfLife
{
    class Grid
    {
    private:
    //Members    
        ...
        using set_of_ints  = std::unordered_set<int>;
        using set_of_sizes = std::unordered_set<std::size_t>;
        //Members to be used in Macros
        set_of_sizes cells_at_t_minus_one;
        set_of_sizes cells_at_t;
        ...
    private:
    //Functions
        ...
        //Function showing Lengthy Conditionals 
        void rule(const std::size_t& cell_position)
        {
            std::size_t live_neighbors{0};

            for(const auto& neighbor_offset : neighbor_offsets)
                /*! Total Neighbors !*/
            {
                //Lengthy Conditional 
                if(cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position + neighbor_offset) != cells_at_t.end())
                {
                    live_neighbors++;
                }
            }
            //Lengthy Conditional
            if(cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position) != cells_at_t.end() and live_neighbors < 2)
                /*! Underpopulation !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.erase(cell_position);
            }
            //Lengthy Conditional
            else if(cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position) != cells_at_t.end() and (live_neighbors == 2 or live_neighbors == 3))
                /*! Aging of a Cell !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.insert(cell_position);
            }
            //Lengthy Conditional
            else if(cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position) == cells_at_t.end() and live_neighbors == 3)
                /*! Birth of a Cell !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.insert(cell_position);
            }
            //Lengthy Conditional
            else if(cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position) != cells_at_t.end() and live_neighbors > 3)
                /*! Overpopulation !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.erase(cell_position);
            }
        }
        public:
        ...
    };
}
...
```

**Code with Macros**

```
...
#define neighbor cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position + neighbor_offset)
#define cell cells_at_t_minus_one.find(cell_position)
#define dead cells_at_t.end()
#define is_live != dead
#define is_dead == dead
#define result second

namespace ConwaysGameOfLife
{
    class Grid
    {
    private:
    //Members    
        ...
        using set_of_ints  = std::unordered_set<int>;
        using set_of_sizes = std::unordered_set<std::size_t>;
        //Members used in Macros
        set_of_sizes cells_at_t_minus_one;
        set_of_sizes cells_at_t;
        ...
    private:
    //Functions
        ...
        void rule(const std::size_t& cell_position)
        {
            std::size_t live_neighbors{0};

            for(const auto& neighbor_offset : neighbor_offsets)
                /*! Total Neighbors !*/
            {
                //Macros used
                if(neighbor is_live)
                {
                    live_neighbors++;
                }
            }
            //Macros used
            if(cell is_live and live_neighbors < 2)
                /*! Underpopulation !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.erase(cell_position);
            }
            //Macros used
            else if(cell is_live and (live_neighbors == 2 or live_neighbors == 3))
                /*! Aging of a Cell !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.insert(cell_position);
            }
            //Macros used
            else if(cell is_dead and live_neighbors == 3)
                /*! Birth of a Cell !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.insert(cell_position);
            }
            //Macros used
            else if(cell is_live and live_neighbors > 3)
                /*! Overpopulation !*/
            {
                cells_at_t.erase(cell_position);
            }
        }
        public:
        ...
    };
}

#undef neighbor
#undef cell
#undef dead
#undef is_live
#undef is_dead
#undef result
...
```

Comment: You can always use inline functions if you think they'll improve readability.

Comment: I tried, but I can not manage to get inline functions to work in a syntax like the macros have worked out.

Comment: Well, consider to have these functions some parameters (which would approve readability additionally).

Comment: Isn't that pure code obfuscation!?

Comment: ... Even worse are macros assuming certain parameters

Comment: If macros were to be safe or if these were inline functions would the second code example be more clear than the first in your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
if (neighbor is_live) { ... }
```

is absolutely impossible to understand. It looks like ill-formed code, and anybody reading it will first and foremost think that there's something wrong there. Forget your peers, this is the sort of code that you will come back to in a few months and not understand for quite some time.

It also yields a lot of problems in that things like `neighbor`, `dead`, `cell`, `result`, and `is_live` are reasonable names to use as identifiers for this particular program. So if you happen to use them as identifiers, you will end up with fairly inscrutable errors.

Consider the alternative:

```
if (is_live(cell_position + neighbor_offset)) { ... }
```

where we just have a function `is_live` that just does the right thing:

```
bool is_live(size_t idx) { return !cells_at_t_minus_one.count(idx); }
```

This is far superior because:

1. It actually looks like syntactically correct code.
2. All the variables we're using are clear and visible in the code.
3. I can use whatever identifiers I want, wherever I want them, and I don't have to worry about the preprocessor overwriting them.
4. My variable names aren't set in stone. If I want to change `neighbor_offset` to just be `offset`, that name change only has effects for the scope of `neighbor_offset` (which in your code doesn't even appear to be used). I don't have to then change the definition of my macro!

---

Side-note, your is live check is comparing iterators from one container (`cells_at_t_minus_one`) with another container (`cells_at_t`).

Answer (score 2):

> I decided to use macros to be short and clear.

translation: I decided that c++ wasn't for me so I invented a new domain-specific language with its own syntax. It really looks quite nice, but since it's completely translated in the preprocessor you can only express the concepts I have explicitly anticipated.

> I was wandering if using macros like this is bad practice.

If by bad practice, you mean that as your program grows and changes it will become unmaintainable then yes it's bad practice.

If by bad practice you mean that your colleagues will be upset with you for creating unmaintainable code, then yes it's bad practice.

In summary...

not just bad practice, the very worst.

Comment: "the very worst" +1 for TRUTH!

Answer (score 0):

My rules of thumb regarding macros are:

1. Avoid using them if you can. Use inline functions or templates instead, because macros are just a text replacement and can cause major issues.
2. If you have to use them, name them very clearly. Try to use names that are not likely to show up anywhere else, because macros are just a text replacement.

Number 2 is to avoid problems like:

```
#define equals ==
int main()
{
    bool equals = 2 equals 3;
    if( equals )
        printf( "2==3 is true?" );
}
```

which ends up as:

```
int main()
{
    bool == = 2 == 3;
    if( == )
        printf( "2==3 is true?" );
}
```

when the macro gets processed.